# Android Audio Recording

Tags: android

I work one application for android audio recording in which i used mediaRecorder 
   class to record sound.now i have to change that sound to other sounds like cartoon 
   sound,and i also want when i stop recording it automatically plays sound 
   I have no idea for that can you please help me out.
   Thanks In advance,any help will be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in a record-then-play-back model of operation, I suppose one way you could generate a "cartoon sound" would be to play the recording back too fast, either by setting a different playback sample rate or doing a sample rate conversion on the data before playing it back at the original rate.

A fancier solution would be to change the pitch without changing the playback rate, for example using something like the http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/ library via the android NDK